# Can a Turkish Sunni Muslim convert into Hindu?

Tags: practical-islam, nikah, sunni

Can a Turkish Sunni Muslim convert into Hindu and any other religion at his wish?

Comment: What is the reason for Turkish? Religious matters don't exclude any ethnicity.

Comment: can Sunni Muslim from any country convert into Hindu or any other religion by their wish? I have heard such cases only in Turkey hence I mentioned.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it is not about Islam, but about laws of apostasy in Turkey.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it is trivia

Answer (score -1, accepted):

There is a hadith forbidding to change religion of a Muslim to any other religion and this hadith states that this kind of act is punishable by death.

Turkey is a laic country, nobody can kill you for that. Also most people in Turkey doesn't care. Even claiming to be an atheist is very cool among some teenager groups (stupid in most of them).

Comment: Ok then he is not cheating He is genuine 

Comment: I just read your other question about this issue and I strongly recommend not to think about serious matters such as marriage with people you don't know. Both internet & Turkey has lots of bad people. First meet him in real life, then learn about him, meet his family etc.

Comment: "There is a hadith forbidding to change religion of a Muslim to any other religion and this hadith states that this kind of act is punishable by death." Meh, this is partly true, but also partly false. It depends purely on how one goes about context. I know the hanifi madhhab has a context when coming to the execution of apostates.

Comment: I agree....he is in government job at good position....I will meet him and his family I already see his family online though but never spoken to them. this comes very last first we should see every aspect and my situation is not easy to leave so it is really tough so I am only favoring a friendship I have asked him to listen to his family. We can at least be friends if not something else yet I want a trusted and truthful friend. Thanks for guidance

Comment: @Opcode, As I said, most Turkish people don't care about this hadith. Probably most of them don't even know it and won't believe it if they hear. I said it because some countries take this hadith very seriously.

Comment: @kalahari I know, I was commenting about it from a Islamic perspective. (About how some Muslims take the hadith without context, and apply it universally, and how some Muslims argue that it has context, etc.)

Comment: But then will marriage be legal without following Hadith? I am feeling immensely depressed I m sorry

Comment: The hadith is about changing religion. Marriage of a Muslim man is limited by Quran and nobody can argue about that. But of course he might change his religion without harm (in Turkey), or he can just ignore that religious rule. Its depend on him. I wrote this information about hadith because in some countries that death penalty is really applied. Not in Turkey.

Comment: I mean, because Turkey is not governed by Islam's rules, you can marry with him without any problem, with the laic state marriage. Turkey only recognizes that, not the Islamic one. But if he is a religious man and wants the Islamic marriage too, then this would be a problem in the religious contex.

Comment: If he converts into Hindu and marry as per Hindu customs then there is no question of islamic marriage may be he can marry Islamic and laic both ways with one girl

Comment: Islamic Hindu laic all ways with one girl that too converting to Hindu. And this he has already told me so he is right, only clarification I need will be his marital status his age and his criminal background. Girls should not flow into emotions to take such important decisions of their life. This is for safety and lifetime happiness

Comment: If he convert to Hindu, then we can't put any rules of Islam, it would be awkward. But religion is not a toy, this may cause problems in the Afterlife, if we assume Islam is right and Hinduism is wrong. About his criminal status, I really don't know how to check it. In Turkey, only legal authorities like police or courts can check it. Please take it slow & learn as much as you can about him, be careful.

Answer (score -1):

Asalamu aliakum,

I am not a scholar at first, just interested in what questions arise in the ummah. First of all, I don't think there is a way to convert back to 'Hinduism', you need to be more specific in what you are asking.

Why would someone convert to Hinduism when Islam gives you peace and direct. While, Hinduism has so many rules and regulations that don't make much sense on why you are instructed to do so and it's not beneficial to you.

And As Always "Allahu 'Alim".

Whatever right I have said was because of Allah (SWT) and whatever I have said wrong was because of me and Shaytaan.

~Wa aliakum Asalam.

Comment: The questioner is already Hindu. She is asking for another person.

Answer (score -1):

Totally, Islam is a religion whish doesn't agree you or other Muslims to change their religions. In fact according to Islam, every muslim who convert from Islam to ... then he would be called as Mortad. Of course being Mortad has some conditions and cases which have mention in the reference below. (of course unfortunately that is not in English). Anyway as it stated in short, you are not allowed to convert your religion which is Islam and it doesnt seem to be permitted even if you wish to do that. because there should be a negative matter in the mind which made you being interested in wishing in the question. Then there is no difference if he is a Turkish muslim or etc.  Reference:  http://www.tebyan.net/newindex.aspx?pid=209666

Answer (score -3):

yes. you can convert to Hindu as Hinduism is the most oldest and peaceful religion that never invaded the others and its doors are open too all. Hinduism is like living democracy as it allows you to pray the god by the way you like thats why you can convert to Hinduism very easily.

Comment: Welcome to Islam.SE! Answers here should be elaborate, and focused on answering the question. Claims should be supported by evidence. Please visit our [tour](https://islam.stackexchange.com/tour) in the [help center](https://islam.stackexchange.com/help), and refer to [how to answer questions](https://islam.stackexchange.com/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score -4):

A man has fundamental right to change his religion according to his belief. I know this only. I know no rules, no traditions, and no customs. Do what you feel as right!

Comment: So if someone thinks that raping and killing is right, then by your logic they should go ahead?!!!?!

Comment: Salam and welcome to Islam SE. Unlike the typical internet forums we expect answers to be well focused and elaborated and your claims supported by evidences. Therefore i strongly recommend you to take our [tour], check our [help] and read [answer] to learn more about this site.